# Set position for custom CollectionEditor form in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, position, windows-forms-designer, collectioneditor

I wrote a custom collection editor for a WinForms control. Its core code looks like this:

```cs
internal class MyCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    public MyCollectionEditor(Type type) : base(type) { }

    protected override System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor.CollectionForm CreateCollectionForm()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor.CollectionForm myForm = base.CreateCollectionForm();

        #region Adjust the property grid

        PropertyGrid myPropGrid = GetPropertyGrid(myForm);
        if (myPropGrid != null)
        {
            myPropGrid.CommandsVisibleIfAvailable = true;
            myPropGrid.HelpVisible = true;
            myPropGrid.PropertySort = PropertySort.CategorizedAlphabetical;
        }

        #endregion

        return myForm;
    }
}
```

I need to set a custom size and location for the collection editor form, but I could not find a way to do that. It seems the collection editor form is always positioned by VS to its default location. Is there a way to do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It respects to the [`StartPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition(v=vs.110).aspx),  [`DesktopLocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.desktoplocation(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Size`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25w4thew(v=vs.110).aspx) which you set for the form:

```
public class MyCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    public MyCollectionEditor() : base(typeof(Collection<Point>)) { }
    protected override CollectionForm CreateCollectionForm()
    {
        var form = base.CreateCollectionForm();
        // Other Settings
        // ...
        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        form.Size = new Size(900, 600);
        form.DesktopLocation = new Point(10, 10);
        return form;
    }
}
```

Then decorate your property this way:

```
[Editor(typeof(MyCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public Collection<Point> MyPoints { get; set; }
```

Comment: Off-topic, but since you are customizing collection editor, you also may find this post helpful: [How to enable Default Values for properties in a 'CollectionEditor' dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517211/how-to-enable-default-values-for-properties-in-a-collectioneditor-dialog)

Comment: I try to restore the form position using one property, DesktopBounds, but the for size is always increased with every assignment to the DesktopBounds property. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @TecMan You can also use `SetDesktopBounds` without any problem, but you should first set `StartPosition` to `FormStartPosition.Manual`.

Comment: Sure I set `StartPosition` to `Manual` first. It seems, the VS designer does something special and the form is expanded a little bit every time after I change its size/position in CreateCollectionForm. However, I solved my problem by placing the code that restores the position in the Load event for myForm.