# C# Winform CollectionPropertiesEditor - How to hide some properties in the built-in PropertyGrid based on runtime condition

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, propertygrid

Is there a way to hide show properties in “CollectionPropertiesEditor’s PropertyGrid”
Recently I found out that there is a way to change the PropertyGrid’s Browsable attribute at run time.

I want to know if this can be done to a “CollectionPropertiesEditor’s PropertyGrid”, I have been un-successful at finding relevant results on Google Search. Now I have my hopes on StackOverflow to help me solve this problem.

Problem: I had to add some properties to GridColumn control due to new customer requirements.

```
    [Category("Extra")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    public int? Position { get; set; }

    [Category("Extra")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    public string storedColumn { get; set; }
```

What I was hoping to work earlier:

```
    [Category("Extra")]
    [Browsable(matchSomeRunTimeCondition)]
    public int? Position { get; set; }

    [Category("Extra")]
    [Browsable(matchSomeRunTimeCondition)]
    public string storedColumn { get; set; }
```

**Why it does not work?**

Because Browsable Attribute can only accept Constant. And `matchSomeRunTimeCondition` is not a constant. A user can change it when-ever he wants while the application is still running.

In code if there is a function that I can use to make these invisible at run-time I will be really greatful if someone can help me write one such function or conditional statement like so:

> If (property’s category == “Extra”) {
>
> //Do not show this property in the propertygrid.
>
> //Or in other words, make Browasable Attribute False at run time.
>
> }

At compile time I am setting the Browsable property to `true` because it needs to be visible in some conditions. But I need a mechanism to hide this based on user's choice at runtime.

This problem was overcome in the propertygrid by means of setting it while loading the selected control as explained the post:  [Make all properties with specific Category name invisible in PropertyGrid in c# Winforms at Runtime based on some condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785729/make-all-properties-with-specific-category-name-invisible-in-propertygrid-in-c-s)

However in the CollectionPropertiesEditor that I use to hold my grid columns does not have this luxury (at least I could not find out how to do it).

I store all the grid columns of my grid in the form of list of GridColumns as a property.

This is how I am currently storing the GridColumns in the Grid’s properties:

```
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Editor(typeof(CollectionPropertiesEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public List<TGridColumn> Columns { get; set; }
```

[image]

[image]
Here I don’t know how to pass my condition to make the aforementioned columns disappear at runtime.

Comment: You should write your own type descriptor by deriving from `CustomTypeDescriptor` or implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor`. For example take a look at this post: [Combining multiple Attributes to a single Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38503146/3110834)

Comment: hi @RezaAghaei, nice to see you after so long. Let me go over your solution and get back (will probably take some time).

Comment: Hi, nice to see you too :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I could not understand how to use your solution to solve this problem.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, do you know if there is too much effort involved in creating a custom CollectionPropertiesEditor?

Comment: I guess you can simply achieve the desired behavior using the link which I provided. I'll give it a try and notify you.

Comment: You want to make invisible, all properties which have: `[Category("Extra")]` attribute?

Comment: yes. I want to make it inside the CollectionsPropertyEditor.

Comment: I have done it for a form with property grid as shown in this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785729/make-all-properties-with-specific-category-name-invisible-in-propertygrid-in-c-s). But this CollectionsPropertyEditor is new to me and I dont see any Event handlers I can use for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your own type descriptor by deriving from `CustomTypeDescriptor` or implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor`. Here is an example:

**MyPropertyDescriptor**

Provide a custom description for a property. Here I override `Attributes` property to provide a new list of attributes for property. For example I check if the property has `[Category("Extra")]`, I also added a `[Browsable(false)]` to its attribute collection.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
public class MyPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    PropertyDescriptor o;
    public MyPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor originalProperty)
        : base(originalProperty) { o = originalProperty; }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    { return o.CanResetValue(component); }
    public override object GetValue(object component) { return o.GetValue(component); }
    public override void ResetValue(object component) { o.ResetValue(component); }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value) 
    { o.SetValue(component, value); }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) 
    { return o.ShouldSerializeValue(component); }
    public override AttributeCollection Attributes
    {
        get
        {
            var attributes = base.Attributes.Cast<Attribute>().ToList();
            var category = attributes.OfType<CategoryAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (category != null && category.Category == "Extra")
                attributes.Add(new BrowsableAttribute(false));
            return new AttributeCollection(attributes.ToArray());
        }
    }
    public override Type ComponentType { get { return o.ComponentType; } }
    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return o.IsReadOnly; } }
    public override Type PropertyType { get { return o.PropertyType; } }
}
```

**MyTypeDescriptor**

Used to provide a list of custom property descriptors for a type.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
public class MyTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    ICustomTypeDescriptor original;
    public MyTypeDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor originalDescriptor)
        : base(originalDescriptor) { original = originalDescriptor; }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    { return this.GetProperties(new Attribute[] { }); }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var properties = base.GetProperties(attributes).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                             .Select(p => new MyPropertyDescriptor(p))
                             .ToArray();
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties);
    }
}
```

**MyTypeDescriptionProvider**

Used to connect `MyTypeDescriptor` to a class using `TypeDescriptionProvider` attribute.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
public class MyTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    public MyTypeDescriptionProvider()
        : base(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(object))) { }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type type, object o)
    {
        ICustomTypeDescriptor baseDescriptor = base.GetTypeDescriptor(type, o);
        return new MyTypeDescriptor(baseDescriptor);
    }
}
```

**MySampleClass**

Contains a property decorated with `[Category("Extra")]`. So `Property2` will not be visible in property grid. (In visual studio or collection editor or even run-time property grid)

```
[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(MyTypeDescriptionProvider))]
public class MySampleClass
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    [Category("Extra")]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

**MyComplexComponent**

Contains a collection of `MySampleClass`. So you can see behavior of `MySampleClass` in collection editor.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
public class MyComplexComponent:Component
{
    public MyComplexComponent()
    {
        MySampleClasses = new Collection<MySampleClass>();
    }
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Collection<MySampleClass> MySampleClasses { get; set; }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Wow @RezaAghaei, what a quick solution. I will get back after trying out your answer. I am taking some time to understand what is going on.

Comment: No problem. This is the way which type descriptors work. They are metadata engine which uses in property grid.

Comment: I copied your code into separate .cs files with the same name as the title provided above for each code sample. Could you show me the code that made the screenshot appear?

Comment: Build your project and drop a `MyComplexComponent` on a form. Then check its `MySampleClasses` property which opens a collection editor.

Comment: I didnt notice that earlier. It appears in the toolbox and it gets shown in the bottom area under the form.

Comment: I wanted to know where the Add/Remove; Up/down; Ok Cancel buttons coming from? and how are you setting the labels on this control?

Comment: @codefrenzy They belong to `CollectionEditor` form. You can create a new one or customize the existing. For example take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35520990/3110834).