# How to create a Browse-able property for class with type dictionary

Tags: vb.net, properties, browsable

I created a class that inherits button in win forms
How can i create a **Browsable** property with type **dictionary** ?

here is my code
but i didn't find it in properties menu 
vb.net

```
<Browsable(True)>
Property Set_ddn() As Dictionary(Of TextBox, String)
    Get
        Return ddn
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Dictionary(Of TextBox, String))
        ddn = value
    End Set
End Property
```

how can i make it browsable ?
or what should i use instead of dictionary?

or another solution

Comment: Any property that exposes a collection should almost certainly be `ReadOnly`.  You want to be able to get the collection and then add, remove or set items in it but you don't want to be able to replace the existing collection with a completely different one.

Comment: I just tested and, as I suspected, a property of type `Dictionary(Of TextBox, String)` is browsable by default, whether `ReadOnly` or not.  "Browsable" simply means displayed in the Properties window at design time.  I suspect that the question you actually want answered is how can you add items to the `Dictionary` at design time.  There's nothing available by default to select `TextBox` keys and `String` values that way.  You would have to build your own design-time editor.

Comment: thanks bro  ....so my question is how can i create a browsable collection to insert ,remove,update items like columns property in datagridview ?

Comment: That is something for you to research and then post a question here if and when you run into a specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer here (C#)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42829336/1543991

rewrite code for `vb.net`

You should write your own type descriptor by deriving from `CustomTypeDescriptor` or implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor`. Here is an example:

**MyPropertyDescriptor**

Provide a custom description for a property. Here I override Attributes property to provide a new list of attributes for property. For example I check if the property has `[Category("Extra")]`, I also added a `[Browsable(false)]` to its attribute collection.

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Linq

Public Class MyPropertyDescriptor
Inherits PropertyDescriptor

Private o As PropertyDescriptor

Public Sub New(ByVal originalProperty As PropertyDescriptor)
    MyBase.New(originalProperty)
    o = originalProperty
End Sub

Public Overrides Function CanResetValue(ByVal component As Object) As Boolean
    Return o.CanResetValue(component)
End Function

Public Overrides Function GetValue(ByVal component As Object) As Object
    Return o.GetValue(component)
End Function

Public Overrides Sub ResetValue(ByVal component As Object)
    o.ResetValue(component)
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub SetValue(ByVal component As Object, ByVal value As Object)
    o.SetValue(component, value)
End Sub

Public Overrides Function ShouldSerializeValue(ByVal component As Object) As Boolean
    Return o.ShouldSerializeValue(component)
End Function

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Attributes As AttributeCollection
    Get
        Dim attributes = MyBase.Attributes.Cast(Of Attribute)().ToList()
        Dim category = attributes.OfType(Of CategoryAttribute)().FirstOrDefault()
        If category IsNot Nothing AndAlso category.Category = "Extra" Then attributes.Add(New BrowsableAttribute(False))
        Return New AttributeCollection(attributes.ToArray())
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ComponentType As Type
    Get
        Return o.ComponentType
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly As Boolean
    Get
        Return o.IsReadOnly
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property PropertyType As Type
    Get
        Return o.PropertyType
    End Get
End Property
End Class
```

**MyTypeDescriptor**

Used to provide a list of custom property descriptors for a type.

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Linq

Public Class MyTypeDescriptor
    Inherits CustomTypeDescriptor

    Private original As ICustomTypeDescriptor

    Public Sub New(ByVal originalDescriptor As ICustomTypeDescriptor)
        MyBase.New(originalDescriptor)
        original = originalDescriptor
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function GetProperties() As PropertyDescriptorCollection
        Return Me.GetProperties(New Attribute() {})
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetProperties(ByVal attributes As Attribute()) As PropertyDescriptorCollection
        Dim properties = MyBase.GetProperties(attributes).Cast(Of PropertyDescriptor)().[Select](Function(p) New MyPropertyDescriptor(p)).ToArray()
        Return New PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties)
    End Function
End Class
```

**MyTypeDescriptionProvider**

Used to connect `MyTypeDescriptor` to a class using `TypeDescriptionProvider` attribute.

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MyTypeDescriptionProvider
    Inherits TypeDescriptionProvider

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(GetType(Object)))
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function GetTypeDescriptor(ByVal type As Type, ByVal o As Object) As ICustomTypeDescriptor
        Dim baseDescriptor As ICustomTypeDescriptor = MyBase.GetTypeDescriptor(type, o)
        Return New MyTypeDescriptor(baseDescriptor)
    End Function
End Class
```

**MySampleClass**

Contains a property decorated with [Category("Extra")]. So `Property2` will not be visible in property grid. (In visual studio or collection editor or even run-time property grid)

```
<TypeDescriptionProvider(GetType(MyTypeDescriptionProvider))>
Public Class MySampleClass
    Public Property Property1 As Integer
    <Category("Extra")>
    Public Property Property2 As String
End Class
```

**MyComplexComponent**

Contains a collection of `MySampleClass`. So you can see behavior of `MySampleClass` in collection editor.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MyComplexComponent
    Inherits Component

    Public Sub New()
        MySampleClasses = New Collection(Of MySampleClass)()
    End Sub

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public Property MySampleClasses As Collection(Of MySampleClass)
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: In the Property Descriptor, you have a local variable, "attributes" in the property "Attributes."  While in C these are unique because of case sensitivity, you can't do that in VB.

Comment: This works well, but I did notice that your code is a Collection, not a Dictionary.